# Ajax call keeps returning null

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

My js:

```
$('#select').change(function() {
    var name = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "data/grab.php",
        data: { type: "hops", name: name },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
            var aa = data['aa'];
            $('#hops-aa').val(aa);
        }
    });
});
```

grab.php

```
<?php

$type = $_POST['type'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

if ($type == 'hops') {
    $result = $name;
}

$result = json_encode($result);
return $result;
```

I added the `alert()` in the ajax call to double check what I'm getting back from the script, and it's always null. Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually `echo` or `print` the `$result`. In PHP using `return` from the file scope does not send the returned value to the output stream.

Answer (score 2):

You use `echo` to print out the results in PHP, not `return`:

```
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

(As previous answers stated)
You need to echo/print the $result variable.

```
<?php

$type = $_POST['type'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

if ($type == 'hops') {
    $result = $name;
}

$result = json_encode($result);
echo $result; // return $result;
?>
```

Comment: Not that, especially when using special output formats and not in the context of a template file, you should not use the PHP closing tag `?>`

Comment: Why is that? Does ?> output a newline? Forgive my ignorance - I've been out of the PHP game for a while.

Comment: Essentially, yes. It's simply a best-practice to avoid any data being given to the output buffer which is not explicitly sent there by the programmer. It's perfectly normal in templates (for obvious reasons) but in "pure-code" files, they are highly discouraged nowadays. Cheers!